# How can I extract the font name from RichTextBox Rtf

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

So lets say my RichTextBox in C# has the specific Rtf code

```
"{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fprq2\fcharset2 Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f3\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Liberation Serif{\*\falt Times New Roman};}"
```

What I want to do is extract the font name from that given Rtf so I could print it into a console.
So I want to just get Times New Roman and and other fonts only that from the given Rtf.

Comment: Your File format is not valid.

Comment: It is only the font table portion. Well you may have to parse it and pick the parts from \fcharsetN to ;